# "with" argument in "data.table" usage confusion

Tags: r, data.table

The data.table syntax with respect to the `with` argument seems to be confusing. Consider the below 4 use cases which select/assign data to columns which has "Petal" in their name

```
library("data.table")
iris1 = as.data.table(iris)

#case - 0
iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) ]

#case - 1
iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) , with=FALSE ] # Correct

#case - 2
# Error in [<-.data.table(*tmp*, , grep("Petal", names(iris1)), with = FALSE,  : unused argument (with = FALSE)
iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) , with=FALSE ] = 5 # Wrong

#case - 3
iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1))  ] = 5 # Correct
```

`Case-1` returns the correct answer, and using `with=FALSE` disables the ability to refer to columns as if they are variables. No problem with that.

But going by that same rule why is `Case-2` throwing error. Shouldn't it behave like

```
iris1[,c(3,4)] = 5
```

To confuse further, `Case-3` works well for assignment without using `with`.

So I have the below question

- Why using `with` in Case-2 causes Errors
- Without using `with` in Case-3 how does it know if it is variable name or column name?
- Shouldn't it be throwing error for Case-0 - because it is encountering names which is not part of column names or functions. Why is it returning selected column numbers alone ?

Comment: Answer to 1: The function used to store or update data as you are doing it, `data.table:::[<-.data.table` doesn't have a `with` argument. (But the real question is: why doesn't it (need to)?)

Comment: Try this for case-2 and 3 instead: `iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) := 5 ]`

Comment: isn't that essentially case 3 only using the `:=` assignment operator on the inside instead of the `=` operator on the outside?

Comment: @zx8754:  `iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) := 5 , with=FALSE ]` works with a warning that "with" is ignored with :=...

Comment: for **case 1** I would definately favor `iris1[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^Petal")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my understanding based on observed behavior and without looking at the internal code (others might chime in here).

It is important to note that `[.data.table` and `[<-.data.table` are two separate functions which behave differently and
which have different arguments.

First, while `[.data.table` has a `with` argument to mimic `[.data.frame`, `[<-.data.table` doesn’t have this argument.
This explains why using `with` in Case-2 throws an errors. We can only speculate about the reasons, why one function supports `with` and the other doesn’t.

Second, `[.data.table` and `[<-.data.table` evaluate the output of inner functions differently.
`[.data.table` seems to capture the output of most functions inside `j`.
First let's look at the output of the inner expression:

```r
grep("Petal", names(iris1))
#> [1] 3 4
```

Now, when we call this function inside `j` we see the output is captured and not further evaluated in the context of columns of `iris1` to select by:

```r
library(data.table)
iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1)) ]
#> [1] 3 4
```

This holds true for almost any function:

```r
foo <- function(){
  c(3,4)
}

iris1[  , foo() ]
#> [1] 3 4
```

I assume the combine function `c()` is a special case whose output is not captured, but further evaluated as column number to select by:

```r
iris1[  , c(3:4) ]
#>      Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   1:          1.4         0.2
#>   2:          1.4         0.2
#>   3:          1.3         0.2
#>   4:          1.5         0.2
#>   5:          1.4         0.2
#>  ---                         
#> 146:          5.2         2.3
#> 147:          5.0         1.9
#> 148:          5.2         2.0
#> 149:          5.4         2.3
#> 150:          5.1         1.8
```

Why capture the output of functions in `j` in the first place?
‘data.table’ allows all kind of operations inside `j`, for example:

```r
iris1[  , round(mean(Petal.Length)) ]
#> [1] 4
```

If the output would be further evaluated in the context of columns to select by, then the result would be different, and certain aggregating operations wouldn’t be possible anymore.

To actually show that the output of most functions is captured (and not further evaluated) we can use `eval(bquote())` and evaluate the result of
the inner function early:

```r
eval(bquote(iris1[  , .(grep("Petal", names(iris1))) ]))
#>      Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   1:          1.4         0.2
#>   2:          1.4         0.2
#>   3:          1.3         0.2
#>   4:          1.5         0.2
#>   5:          1.4         0.2
#>  ---                         
#> 146:          5.2         2.3
#> 147:          5.0         1.9
#> 148:          5.2         2.0
#> 149:          5.4         2.3
#> 150:          5.1         1.8
```

This should explain why case-0 does not throw an error and why case-1 shows a different outcome than case-0.

Finally case-3 uses a different function `[<-.data.table` which doesn’t capture the output of its inner functions, which is why `iris1[  , grep("Petal", names(iris1))  ] <-`
actually selects the correct columns `3` and `4` and accordingly replaces their values with `5`.

Again we could speculate why `[<-.data.table` doesn’t capture the output of the inner functions, but it somehow makes sense, since we don’t need this functionality here. The assignment function doesn’t need to capture the output of functions.

Data from OP

```r
iris1 <- as.data.table(iris)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>